# Variable coordinates in ncurses are not working

Tags: c, variables, ncurses

I'm learning C, and decided to look at ncurses. I'm trting to write a program that moves @ around the screen. Everything works if I specify numbers for the starting coordinates, but if I try to use variable coordinates that center the @ at start, the @ just doesn't appear.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, c, height, width;

    initscr();

    getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;

    mvprintw(x, y, "@");

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);
    while(1) {
        c = wgetch(stdscr);
        switch(c) {
            case KEY_DOWN:
                clear();
                ++x;
                mvprintw(x, y, "@");
                refresh();
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                clear();
                --x;
                mvprintw(x, y, "@");
                refresh();
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                clear();
                mvprintw(x, y, "@");
                refresh();
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                clear();
                --y;
                mvprintw(x, y, "@");
                refresh();
                break;
            }
        }

    return 0;
}


int center() {
    int x, y, width, height;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, width, height);
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
    return x, y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man mvwprintw`

```
   int mvprintw(int y, int x, const char *fmt, ...);
```

Notice where the x and y are.

Also, your code is inconsistent.

```
x = width/2;
```

[...]

```
case KEY_DOWN:
            clear();
            ++x;
            mvprintw(x, y, "@");
            refresh();
            break;
```